# Label a generic type argument bounded with super

Tags: java, generics, types

To specify my rather tricky problem, a bit of explanation is required so please bear with me.

I'm designing minimalist interfaces for an observable pattern that uses managing `ListenerHandles` instead of a `removeListener(...)` method in the observable class.

This is the idea:

```
public interface ListenerHandle<T> {

    boolean isRemoved();
    void remove();

    Listener<T> managedListener();
    Observable<T> containingObservable();
}

public interface Observable<T> {

    T get();
    void set(T value);

    ListenerHandle<T> addListener(Listener<T> listener);
}

public interface Listener<T> {
    void onChange(ListenerHandle<T> handle, T value);
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine.

But what if I wanted `Observable<T>` to **accept more general** `Listener`**s?** `Listener<? super T>`s to be precise. This makes sense, since a listener that expects `? super T` will also accept `T` (it is *contravariant*).

As a consequence, `ListenerHandle` would need to differentiate between `T` of the `Observable` it was obtained from, and `T` of the managed `Listener`:

```
public interface ListenerHandle<TL, TO> {
    // ...

    Listener<TL> managedListener();
    Observable<TO> containingObservable();
}

public interface Observable<TO> {
    // ...

    <TL> ListenerHandle<TL, TO> addListener(Listener<TL> listener);
}

public interface Listener<TL> {
    void onChange(ListenerHandle<TL, ? extends TL> handle, TL value);
}
```

Even though these interfaces will compile, we know that `TL` in

```
    <TL> ListenerHandle<TL, TO> addListener(Listener<TL> listener);
```

is a bit *too* generic, because it can now be *anything*. However, `Observable` should only be able to take listeners, that expect `TO` or its *super types*:

```
    <TL super TO> ListenerHandle<TL, TO> addListener(Listener<TL> listener);
```

This will not work since `super` can only be used on wildcards. So another option is:

```
    ListenerHandle<? super TO, TO> addListener(Listener<? super TO> listener);
```

In this case, however, the caller will lose the information that the returned `ListenerHandle`'s `? super TO` and `listener`'s `? super TO` will be *identical*:

```
Observable<Number> o = ...;
Listener<Object> l = ...;

// does not work, but should (since we know that we passed a Listener<Object>)
ListenerHandle<Object, Number> h = o.addListener(l);
// works but Object is now generalized to ? super Number
ListenerHandle<? super Number, Number> h2 = o.addListener(l);

l = h2.managedListener(); // fails because ? super Number is not (necessarily) Object
```

So, what I need is a way to specify a *labeled* type argument bounded with *super*, to demonstrate, that the bounded generic type of the argument is identical to the bounded generic type of the return type. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a generic parameter `TL` for the type of `Listener`, you could make it a `Listener<? super T>`:

```
public interface ListenerHandle<T> {

    boolean isRemoved();
    void remove();

    Listener<? super T> managedListener();
    Observable<T> containingObservable();
}

public interface Observable<T> {

    T get();
    void set(T value);

    ListenerHandle<T> addListener(Listener<? super T> listener);
}

public interface Listener<T> {

    <TO extends T> void onChange(ListenerHandle<TO> handle, TO value);
//  or:
//  void onChange(ListenerHandle<? extends T> handle, T value);
}
```

---

If you really need to add the `TL` parameter to `ListenerHandle`, I think the only way to do it would be the [static method workaround](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Lower%20Bound%20Type%20Parameters%20of%20Methods):

```
public interface ListenerHandle<TL, TO extends TL> {

    boolean isRemoved();
    void remove();

    Listener<TL> managedListener();
    Observable<TO> containingObservable();
}

public interface Observable<TO> {

    TO get();
    void set(TO value);

//  @Deprecated
    ListenerHandle<?, TO> addListener(Listener<? super TO> listener); // implies ListenerHandle<? super TO, TO>

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <TL, TO extends TL> ListenerHandle<TL, TO> addListener(Observable<TO> observer, Listener<TL> listener) {
        return (ListenerHandle<TL, TO>) observer.addListener(listener);
    }
}

public interface Listener<TL> {

    void onChange(ListenerHandle<TL, ?> handle, TL value); // implies ListenerHandle<TL, ? extends TL>
}
```

You would have to remember never to call `obs.addListener(lis)` directly, but instead use `Observable.addListener(obs, lis)`. Marking it as `@Deprecated` would give you a warning, but you'd need to put that on all the overriding methods as well.

Comment: This is indeed valid but (as far as I can see) unfortunately not better than my last approach. In the returned `ListenerHandle` I still lost the information of the _actual_ `Listener` type I passed to the `Observable`, and would have to generalize to `Listener<? super Number>` instead of `Listener<Object>`.

Comment: @Reizo Is it really necessary to know the exact type? It seems like the important part is that it's guaranteed to accept values of the generic type from `ListenerHandle` or `Observable`.

Comment: This is pretty much depending on the use case. I want to write a universal collections library and since the information (about the type) is conceptually present and clear, I'd like to have a way to capture it. However I tend to believe that it's simply not possible... But of course, your objection that it (most likely) is not necessary is pretty justified.